# Extension of positive functionals II

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

This is a follow-up to

[Extension of positive functionals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369944/extension-of-positive-functionals).

Assume that $X=R^n$ with the canonical order (I indicate with $K$ the positive cone, $x \in K$ iff $x_i \ge 0$ for all $i$) and let $L:M \to R$ is a positive functional defined on a subspace of $X$. Then it should be true that $L$ has a positive extension to $X$. Actually, there is an old post here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18593/extending-a-positive-linear-functional-in-finite-dimensions

where the author asks for a simpler proof of the result, but the original proof is not shown.

If $M$ contains an interior point of $K$ the extension follows from Krein-Rutman and if $M \cap K=\{0\}$  (or even if $(Ker L) \cap K=\{0\}$) from Bauer-Namioka. What to do with in the remaining cases? One could add $\epsilon$-times a strictly positive functional but I do not know how to control the norm of the extensions to let $\epsilon \to 0$.

So the question is about a proof of the above result, if this is true as it should be. Finally, I do not know what happens for more general (closed) cones in $R^n$. Thank you to all

Comment: It seems like in an arbitrary positive (with respect to a cone $K$) functional on $M$ has a positive extension to the whole space if and only if there exists a positive constant $c$ such that $d(x,K)\ge c d(x,M\cap K)$ for every $x\in M$ with the norm of the extension controlled by $c^{-1}\|L\|$, but I haven't checked all details yet. So, for a cone in $\mathbb R^d$ that is an intersection of finitely many half-spaces it is always possible but in general there are counterexamples.

Comment: @ Fedja. Thank you very much. I am not sure whether the condition on the distances you wrote above is necessary, but it is surely sufficient. You are right, for polyhedral norms in finite dimension the extension is always possible and I found some old papers by Klee and Mirkil proving that. Everything seems quite obvious, the proofs are not difficult but puzzling because there are small problems at several points and one feels silly after a while. I could give a reference (or even an indication of the proof) for somebody interested.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself but maybe somebody is interested and I give a sketch of the proof based on more general ideas by Mirkil and Klee. The main point is the following

Lemma 1. Let $f_1, \cdots, f_k$ be vectors in $X=R^n$ and $G=\{\sum_{i=1}^k a_if_i, \ a_i \geq 0 \}$. Then $G$ is closed.

This is obvious if the vectors are linearly independent. The proof in the general case is by induction on $k$ and holds in any Banach space.

The following is an easy consequence

Lemma 2. If $M$ is a subspace of $X$, then $M+K$ is closed.

For the proof one considers the quotient map $q$ from $X \to X/M$ (or the orthogonal projection onto $M^{\perp}$) and applies Lemma 1 in $X/M$ to $q(K)$ with $f_i=q(e_i)$ (here $(e_i)$ is the standard basis of $X$). Then $q(K)$ closed in $X/M$ gives $M+K=q^{-1}(q(K))$ closed in $X$.

The proof of the extension of any positive map $f:M \to R$ goes as follows.

Write
$f(x)=(x, x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in M$. We look for $\bar x \in K$ such that $\bar x-x_0 \in M^{\perp}$, so that $x \to (\bar x, x)$ is a positive extension. If such a $\bar x$ does not exist, then $x_0 \not \in K+M^\perp$ which is closed. Hahn-Banach then gives $y$ such that $(x_0,y) <(k+g,y)$ for every $k \in K, g\in M^\perp$.
If $k=0$, then $(x_0,y) < (g,y)$ for any $g \in M^\perp$ yields $y \in M$. But then $(x_0,y)<(k,y)$ for every $k \in K$ gives $(k,y) \ge 0$ for every $k \in K$, hence $y \in K$. Finally, $y \in M\cap K$ but $(x_0,y)<(0,y)=0$, against the positivity of $f$.

Two remarks

1. The same proof works for polyedral cones even in infinite dimension. One has to work with the dual cone in $X'$.
2. The condition $d(x,M \cap(-K)) \le Cd(x,-K)$, see the comment by @fedja, would give a positive extension as an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem. However, I cannot verify it for a general subspace $M$ and I do not know if this is necessary. Please, let know.