# How to prove this (corollary of) hyperplane separation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$X$ is a nonempty convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose element is $x=\left(x_1,...,x_n\right)$.

The theorem is as follows.

If for each $x\in X$, there is an $i \in \left\{1,...,n\right\}$ such that $x_i>0$,
then there exists $\left(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\right)$ where $\lambda_i \geqslant 0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$, such that
$\lambda \cdot x \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in X$
and $\lambda \cdot x>0$, for some $x \in X$.

I was wondering how to prove it. "$\geqslant 0$ for all $x$" should be easy. But I got stuck in "$>0$ for some $x$". I failed to use the proper separation theorem (Theorem 11.3 in Rockafellar (1970)).

Thank you very much!

This was cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504475/how-to-prove-this-corollary-of-hyperplane-separation-theorem?noredirect=1#comment9461236_4504475

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Let $Y$ be the span of $X$, $C=Y\cap (-\infty,0]^n$. Since $X$ and $C$ are disjoint convex sets in $Y$, there exists a non-zero functional $\eta\in Y^*$ which separates (not strictly) $X$ and $C$: $\eta$ is non-positive on $C$ and non-negative on $X$. Since $X$ is of full dimension in $Y$, we have $\eta(x)>0$ for some $x\in X$.

Now note that the coordinate functionals $x\to x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, and the functional $\eta$ on $Y$ satisfy the property "if $x_i$'s are non-negative, then $\eta$ is non-negative". It yields by duality that $\eta$ is a non-negative linear combination of $x_i$'s (as a functional on $Y$, in particular as a function on $X$.)

Comment: Fedor, what do you need $\ Y\ $ for? (It feels unnecessary to me to introduce it; right away, $\ \mathbb R^n\ $ instead of $\ Y\ $ would do fine)?

Comment: @WlodAA $Y$ is used to find a point $x\in X$ in which $\eta(x)\ne 0$

Comment: It feels to me that you are right. (*feelings* as in a disco 80's song :) ). I'll still need to think a bit more about it.

Comment: oh, you are correct. Let's say differently: the coordinate functionals $x\to x_i$ and the functional $\eta$ on $Y$ satisfy the property "if $x_i$'s are non-negative, then $\eta$ is non-negative". It yields by duality that $\eta$ belongs to a cone generated by $x_i$'s.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why is $X$ of full dimension in $Y$? Consider the case of $n=2$. Suppose $X$ is a line segment. Then $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ but $X$ is not of full dimension in $Y$.

Comment: "Full dimension" here means that span of $X$ is $Y$, thus any non-zero functional on $Y$ can not vanish on $X$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov The last paragraph is a little glib for me. I wonder could you elaborate or point me somewhere please? If you take $n=2$, $X= \{ x\mid x_1+x_2 = 0, x_1>0 \}$ then $C=\{0\}$ and the functional $\eta:Y \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\eta(x)= x_1-x_2$ separates $C$ and $X$. If the coordinate function $x \mapsto x_2$ is positive (on $Y$) then $\eta(x) < 0$. I presume I am missing something.

Comment: @copper.hat  On $Y$, $\eta(x) = x_1-x_2$ is the same as $2x_1$, since $x_1+x_2=0$

Comment: @Youem I understand that, but regardless of the representation of $\eta$, if $x_2>0$ then $\eta(x)<0$, so I do not follow the last paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Wait in $Y$ you can not have both $x_1$ and $x_2$ non negative. The statement is always true.

Comment: @copper.hat on $Y$ every functional may be represented as a non-negative linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Saying that a positive functional on $Y$ is a linear combination of the coordinate functionals with positive coefficients, is equivalent to saying that it can be extended to a positive functional on $R^n$. This is true, see this old post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370327/extension-of-positive-functionals-ii. At the moment I do not see any convincing shortcut to the proof outlined above and I would be happy ho have a simpler one.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune is anything wrong with the argument in my answer?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry but I still don't get the full dimension part. In my graph, for that $X$, $Y$ is actually $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take $l_1$ as your $\eta$, there is no $\eta(x)>0$.

Comment: The argument is correct if you use the fact that any positive functional on $Y$ can be extended to the whole space preserving positivity, as in your first answer. I cannot fill the details in your last argument (which would give a simple proof of extendibility)

Comment: @Ypbor on your graph $Y=l_1$ (a line), is not it?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune well, I use the fact: "Let linear functionals $f_1,\ldots,f_n, g$ on $Y$ be chosen so that whenever $x\in Y$ and $f_i(x)\geqslant 0$ for all $i$, then $g(x)\geqslant 0$. Then $g=\sum c_if_i$ for certain non-negative $c_i$'s." Proof: if not, $g$ does not belong to a cone generated by $f_i$'s, thus may be strictly separated from it by certain element $x\in Y^{**}=Y$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I agree! Let me point out the fact that the cone generated by the $f_i$, $g=\sum_i c_i f_i, c_i \geq 0$ is closed. I would say that this is the main point (it is obviously closed if the vectors are independent on $Y$).

Comment: any finitely generated cone is closed (it is a finite unit of cones generated by linearly independent subsets: if $g=c_1f_1+\ldots+c_kf_k\,(*)$  with all $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ positive, but $f_i$'s are linearly dependent,  then adding this dependence with appropriate coefficient to $(*)$ you get a representation of $g$ with lesser number of f's.)

Comment: @FedorPetrov If I understand your proof correctly, you apply the hyperplane separating theorem in $Y$. In my graph, $A$ (0-dimension) is a hyperplane in $Y$ (1-dimension), and it separates $C$ and $X$. But we eventually need a separating hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (for example, the line $l$). I feel that the $\eta$ in your proof only specifies $A$ but not $l$?

Comment: @Ypbor Ah, I want to separate by a linear hyperplane, not by affine. This is possible since one of two convex sets is a cone.

Comment: @FedorPetrov What do you exactly mean by $\eta$ "$\in Y^*$" (is $Y^*$ a typo of $Y$)? I thought in my graph, $A \in Y$ but $l \notin Y$.

Comment: Took me a while. Simple, but rather subtle.

Comment: @Ypbor $Y^*$ is a dual space of $Y$, so $\eta$ is a linear functional

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, true. I know also a proof by induction which is perhaps less evident, but closedness is crucial. By the way, I do not know an example in finite dimension where a positive functional defined on a subspace cannot be extended to the whole $R^d$ preserving positivity (positivity being defined with respect to a suitable cone $K$), do you?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Could you please elaborate on why $Y$ is the span of $X$ implies $\eta(x)>0$ for some $x$? I am sorry but it is nontrivial for me.

Comment: @Ypbor If $\eta$ vanishes on $X$, then it vanishes on $Y$, while it is a non-zero functional. Then there is $x \in X$ such that $\eta(x)\neq 0$ and then $\eta (x)>0$ since $\eta \geq 0$ on $X$.

Comment: @Ypbor It took me a while to unravel. $Y$ is the span of $X$ so any functional that is zero on $X$ must be zero on $Y$. Since $\eta \ge 0$ on $X$, since it is non zero, it must be $>0$ somewhere on $X$. Note that $\cap_K \{ y \in Y | e_k (y) \ge 0 \} \subset \{ y \in Y | \eta(y) \ge 0 \}$ and taking the dual gives $\operatorname{sp} \{ \eta \} \subset +_k \operatorname{sp} \{ e_k \}$, so we can write $\eta = \sum_k \lambda_k e_k$ with $\lambda_k \ge 0$.

Comment: (Cont.) Now consider this as **extending** $\eta$ onto all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, we see that the extended $\eta$ is non positive on $(-\infty,0]^n$, non negative on $X$ and $\eta(x)>0$ for some $x \in X$.

Comment: @copper.hat Why is $\cap_K \left\{y \in Y | e_k(y) \geq 0\right\} \subset \left\{y \in Y|\eta(y) \geq 0\right\}$ true? (2) What does "taking the dual" mean? (3) What are the meanings of notation $sp$ and $+_k$?

Comment: @Ypbor The notations mean span and sum respectively. The dual of the intersections is the sum of the duals (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356026/27978).

Comment: @Ypbor If $y\ge 0$ (that is, component wise) and $y \in Y$ then $-y \in C$ and so $\eta(-y) \le 0$, hence $\eta(y) \ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat It seems that you suggested (1) $A \subset B$ implies $\mbox{dual} B \subset \mbox{dual} A$, and (2) $\mbox{dual}\left\{y \in Y | e_k(y) \geq 0\right\}=sp\left\{e_k\right\}$. Why are they true?

Comment: @Ypbor Please replace span by convex cone generated by...

Comment: @copper.hat By "taking the dual", do you mean "dual space" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) or "dual cone" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone)?

Comment: @Ypbor dual cone. Unfortunately comments are not the best place for clarification.

Comment: @FedorPetrov If you don't mind, I might add my elaborations as an answer to the corresponding question on MSE, with appropriate attribution, of course.

Comment: @copper.hat I do not mind

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$Let $\R_-:=(-\infty,0]$ and $\R_+:=[0,\infty)$. The desired statement is equivalent to the following:

> Suppose that
> \begin{equation*}
>     \forall x\in X\ \exists i\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}\ x_i>0. \tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation*}
> Then there is some $\nu\in\R_+^n$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
>     \nu\cdot X:=\{\nu\cdot x\colon x\in X\}\subseteq\R_+\quad\text{and}\quad \nu\cdot X\ne\{0\}.  \tag{2}\label{2}
> \end{equation*}

*Proof:*
Condition \eqref{1} means that $X\cap\R_-^n=\emptyset$. So, by Theorem 11.3 in Rockafellar (1970), there is some $\la^1\in\R^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\la^1\cdot X\subseteq\R_+$ and  $\la^1\cdot\R_-^n\subseteq\R_-$. Also, $\la^1\cdot\R_-^n\subseteq\R_-$ means that $\la^1\in\R_+^n$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    \text{$\la^1\in\R_+^n\setminus\{0\}$ and $\la^1\cdot X\subseteq\R_+$.} \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}

So, either \eqref{2} holds with $\la^1$ in place of $\nu$ or
$\la^1\cdot X=\{0\}$.
So, without loss of generality (wlog), $\la^1\cdot X=\{0\}$. That is, we have
\begin{equation*}
    X\subseteq V^1:=\{x\in\R^n\colon\la^1\cdot x=0\}. 
\end{equation*}
The condition $\la^1\in\R_+^n\setminus\{0\}$ in \eqref{3} implies that wlog for some $k^1\in[n]$ and all $i\in[n]$
\begin{equation*}
    \la^1_i>0\text{ if }i\le k^1\quad \text{and}\quad \la^1_i=0\text{ if }i>k^1. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}

Now condition \eqref{1} implies $X\cap V^1_-=\emptyset$, where $V^1_-:=V^1\cap\R_-^n$. Applying now Theorem 11.3 in Rockafellar (1970) to the Euclidean space $V^1$, we see that there is some $\mu^1\in V^1\setminus\{0\}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu^1\cdot X\subseteq\R_+
\end{equation*}
and $\mu^1\cdot(V^1\cap\R_-^n)\subseteq\R_-$. The latter condition means that for all $x\in\R^n$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    (\la^1\cdot x=0\ \&\ x\in\R_-^n)\implies\mu^1\cdot x\le0
\end{equation*}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation*}
    (\la^1\cdot x=0\ \&\ x\in\R_+^n)\implies\mu^1\cdot x\ge0. \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
Substituting the $i$th standard basis vector $e_i$ for $x$ in \eqref{5}, and recalling \eqref{4}, we get $\mu^1_i=\mu^1\cdot e_i\ge0$ for $i>k$.

So, wlog there is some real $t^1>0$ such that for
\begin{equation*}
    \la^2:=\la^1+t^1\mu^1 \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation*}
and some integer $k^2\in[k^1,n]$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \la^2_i>0\text{ if }i\le k^2\quad \text{and}\quad \la^2_i=0\text{ if }i>k^2. \tag{4a}\label{4a}
\end{equation*}
Also, by \eqref{6}, $\la^2\cdot X\subseteq\la^1\cdot X+t^1\mu^1\cdot X\subseteq\R_+$. So, either \eqref{2} holds with $\la^2$ in place of $\nu$ or
$\la^2\cdot X=\{0\}$ and hence $\mu^1\cdot X=\{0\}$.
So, wlog, $\la^2\cdot X=\{0\}=\mu^1\cdot X$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    X\subseteq V^2:=\{x\in V^1\colon\la^2\cdot x=0\}
    =\{x\in V^1\colon\mu^1\cdot x=0\}\subsetneq V^1;  
\end{equation*}
the latter strict inclusion follows because $\mu^1\in V^1\setminus\{0\}$.

Continuing thus, in $n$ similar steps wlog we will get $X\subseteq V^n:=\{0\}$, which contradicts \eqref{1}. $\quad\Box$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have some questions. (1) How can you guarantee that $\mu^1 \in V^1$? (2) Why is $\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \lambda^2 \cdot x=0\right\}=\left\{x \in V^1: \mu^1 \cdot x=0\right\}$? Why doesn't $\lambda^1 \cdot x>0$ and $\mu^1 \cdot x<0$ work? (3) Why does $V^n$ eventually shrink to ${0}$?

Comment: @Ypbor : (1) Theorem 11.3 in the Rockafellar book is stated for $R^n$, but is clearly applicable to any finite-dimensional Euclidean space. I applied this theorem to the subspace $V_1$ of the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, since $X\subseteq V_1$ and $V^1_-\subseteq V_1$. So, we automatically have $\mu^1\in V^1\setminus\{0\}$. (2) The definition of $V^2$ was incorrect. It is corrected now. (3) The inclusion $V^2\subsetneq V^1$ is strict. Continuing such steps, wlog we will get $V^n\subsetneq V^{n-1}\cdots\subsetneq V^1$. Since the dimension of $V_1$ is $n-1$, the dimension of $V_n$ is $0$.

Comment: @losif Pinelis, the hyperplane is in $V^1$, but $\mu^1$, which is the normal vector, is not in $V^1$.

Comment: @Ypbor : To understand this point, **forget** that $V^1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ -- look at $V^1$ as a Euclidean space on its own. By Theorem 11.3 in the Rockafellar book applied to $V^1$ (instead of $R^n$), there is (say) a nonzero linear functional $l$ on $V^1$ such that $l(X)\subseteq\mathbb R_+$ and $l(V_-^1)\subseteq\mathbb R_-$. The linear functional $l$ on $V^1$ is given by the formula $l(x)=\mu_1\cdot x$ for some nonzero $\mu^1\in V^1$ and all $x\in V^1$. So, $\mu^1\cdot X\subseteq\mathbb R_+$ and $\mu^1\cdot V_-^1\subseteq\mathbb R_-$. And, of course, $\mu^1\in V^1$.

Comment: In my graph, $X=\left\{(x_1, x_2) | x_1+x_2=0, x_1 \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\right\}$, $V^1=\left\{(x_1, x_2)| x_1+x_2=0\right\}$, and $V_{-}^1$ is just the origin. Note that the dimension of $V^1$ is 1, so a hyperplane should be of dimension 0. For example, point $A$ is a hyperplane (with respect to $V^1$) that separates $X$ and $V_{-}^1$. Of course, $A \in V^1$, but what is the $\mu^1$ corresponding to $A$? (Note $\mu^1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: @Ypbor : In this case, you can take e.g. $\mu^1=(1,-1)\in V^1\subset\mathbb R^2$. Generally, I suggest you re-read my previous comment and let me know of the first place that seems unclear to you (if such a place exists). Also, be specific. E.g., instead of just "a hyperplane", say specifically what hyperplane you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I had an answer for both part, but for the moment, I succeed only on the first part, which is an application of the first separation theorem given in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem

By assumption, $X$ and $\mathbb{R}_-^n$ are two disjoint non-empty convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. There exist some non-null vector $c$ such that $X \subset \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : c \cdot x \ge 0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_-^n \subset \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : c \cdot x \le 0\}$.

The last condition applied to opposite of the vectors of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (containd in $\mathbb{R}_-^n$) forces $c$ to have non-negative coordinates. Of course, one may divide $c$ by the sum of its coordinate (which is strictly positive).